# Tensorflow error in training : tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to train a model for detecting cats in photos using a CNN. And I have been using these datasets :

1. https://www.kaggle.com/shaunthesheep/microsoft-catsvsdogs-dataset
2. https://www.kaggle.com/balraj98/facades-dataset

I have been getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input size should match (header_size + row_size * abs_height) but they differ by 2
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_962]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

And this is the code(I reused and tweaked this from an earlier project):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import os
import PIL 
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


batch_size = 64
img_height = 180
img_width = 180





train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  "D://datasets and work//archive(2)//PetImages",
  validation_split=0.2,

  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  "D://datasets and work//archive(2)//PetImages",
  validation_split=0.2,

  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)



class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

num_classes = 2
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1)
])

# horizontal image flipping is ok, chexnet did it;implement it later, Sahal
model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'),
  layers.Conv2D(8, 2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
#  layers.Dropout(0.1),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

(I am using TensorFlow version 2.4.0 and Python version 3.8.7)

Comment: can you update on how have you fixed it please ?

Comment: sorry to disappoint you but....

Comment: i didnt lmao....